Thread Disappeared After Partial Execution in Transactional Block without Rollback in Springboot
I have written the code just like below:
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void migrationMethod(params...) {
    try {
      for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
         jdbcTemplate.update(sql+i+".sql", args...); //each time, this updates some tables
         //omitted the logs and irrelevant code for brevity
       }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
     throw e;
    }
}

I have tested this code for failure and for failure, it can rollback successfully.
Problem step by step:

For a particular case, this code was executed during deployment (we have multiple instances running on different servers to maintain zero downtime).
When I checked the Logs, I could see that it only executed two scripts(first 2 scripts) whereas it was supposed to execute 5 scripts as per the loop you see above.
The rest 3 scripts never executed. Also, there is no trace of failure or exception in the logs.
The database is affected only by the two scripts it executed.

So, I am having hard time to understand, what happened to the rest of the scripts execution or at least I could expect a successful rollback for that transaction, right?
Can anyone share any insight on this weird scenario, please?
